# Particles height adjusment

Tags: particles

Hair-type particles are intersected somewhere in the middle. Is there a way to move them up a little? I can't find anything in the properties panel that would work.

[image]

Comment: Move the object your are using as particle a bit upwards in Edit mode so that the bottom of the ball is at the object's local origin.

Comment: Didn't know it was that simple - I've posted the comment as answer for future viewers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the object your are using as particle a bit upwards in Edit mode so that the bottom of the ball is at the object's local origin.